# Trying to split a string on multiple spaces

Tags: java

```
public Graph(String graphFile) throws IOException {
    int u, v;
    int e, wgt;
    Node t;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(graphFile));
    String graphType = sc.next();
    boolean undirected = true;
    if (graphType.equals("directed")) {
        undirected = false;
    }

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(graphFile);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String splits = " +";  // multiple whitespace as delimiter
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String[] parts = line.split(splits);
    System.out.println("Parts[] = " + parts[0] + " " + parts[1]); // THE ERROR IS THIS LINE

    V = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    E = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
}


public class PrimLists {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int s = 2;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter graph input file name:");
        String file = sc.nextLine();
        Graph g = new Graph(file); // THE ERROR IS THIS LINE
        //Graph g = new Graph(fname);

        g.display();
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Graph.<init>(PrimLists.java:170)
    at PrimLists.main(PrimLists.java:315)
```

I am reading in a text file graph which is this:

```
9
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
A B 1
B C 2
C E 7
E G 1
G H 8
F H 3
F D 4
D E 5
I F 9
I A 3
A D 1
```

Does anyone know why this is not working and could help me out??

Comment: Your question is a little bit hard to understand in its current state. It would be helpful if you could clarify what exactly your question is rather than simply asking for help debugging your code. You can also check out [these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some advice.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not correct

```
String splits = " +";  // multiple whitespace as delimiter
```

You probably meant a proper regular expression of

```
String splits = "\\s+";  // multiple whitespace as delimiter
```

The problem is that your strings do not contain a literal `" +"`, and so they were not being split.

Also note that any line that does not have any spaces on it, such as about the first 10 you've shown will error at `parts[1]`, so you should check `parts.length` first.

Comment: Yeah changed the spits there still not working that is the skeleton code given to us by the lecturer and I just had to implement the algorithm. I think he is just a bit thick haha cheers anyway

Comment: Any index out of bounds exception is a very easy one to fix. I simply pointed you to the cause, not the solution